# Within Ruby on Rails, can I use a new controller to display column information obtained from a form on another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created my first controller named Articles that has a form that gathers info into a column named Name and Title. 
The index page of this displays the column details in alphabetical order.

I created a second controller named Sorted and I am wondering if I can take the table/column data obtained in the first controller and display it on the 
index.html of the second controller?  When I navigate to my www.domain.com/sorted, I get this error:

*SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: articles.title: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" ORDER BY "articles"."title" ASC*

my /views/sorted/index.html.erb...

```
    <h1>Data</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>

      </tr>

      <% @articles.each do |article| %>
       <tr>
         <td><%= article.name %></td>
         <td><%= article.title %></td>
       </tr>
      <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', controller: 'welcome' %>
    <p>
    </table>
```

I have this in my articles_controller.rb which make index.html output info in alphabetical order...

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all.order(:title)
end
```

My routes.rb contains this...

```
  resources :articles

  resources :cases
```

Comment: Remember: a controller is not a model! The model represents the data, the controller helps access data.

Comment: You don't need the second controller, but options passed via url that can be captured via your first controller to perform the sort.

Comment: You will need to add a route (please check Rails Routes article) and have that direct to the other controller with optional parameters. If you are only displaying the data from one model(db table) you only need one controller, not two. There are a lot of options to do what I believe you want to do,

Comment: So say I put this in my controller...  @sorter = Article.where(calibertitle: '308')  and I want to create an index2.html.erb page.  What is the simplest way to do this?  I just want to create a second page in the same controller but I am not finding a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a variable in that index action for the other data you want.

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all.order(:title)
  @cases = Cases.all
end
```

Now you can reference the cases data and the articles data in that view.